# openbd upgrading jetty version 8 to version 9

Tags: coldfusion, jetty, openbd

We have centOS based system where openbd is setup with jetty version 8.1
My requirement is now to upgrade the version of 8 to latest 9.x.x version.

I do not find the exact example to do this.
Please help me to basic steps to do OR kindly share some experience how I can achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: I am able to upgrade jetty server, this is helpful for others. I downloaded the jetty 9 server into openbdjam repository and given name as jetty9 and then go to sh file which is used to start and stop it. where I updated the path for jetty to jetty9. and reboot the server and it worked well. thanks.

Comment: This was very helpfull question.Even I got stuck on this issue.